# Enabling androidX causes 'Cannot change strategy of configuration ':app:compile' after it has been resolved' error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

I am currently trying to migrate OpenId/Android-Apputh to androidX and facing a strange problem after performing all changes gradle starts throwing the following error :

```
> Cannot change strategy of configuration ':app:compile' after it has been resolved.
```

After I add

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

to 'gradle.properties'

**Hint**

I tried to log all possible (using `println(cofigBlockName)`) configuration blocks and found that `sourceSets` configBlock was not called during the build process. So it could be that Jetifier applies some settings to `sourceSets`.

Does anybody know how to fix that?

**android-common.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.versionNum
        versionName rootProject.versionName
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        main.java.srcDirs = ['java']
        main.aidl.srcDirs = ['java']
        main.res.srcDir 'res'
        main.assets.srcDir 'assets'
        main.resources.srcDir 'java'
        test.setRoot('javatests');
        test.java.srcDir('javatests');
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        warningsAsErrors true
        disable 'InvalidPackage', 'TrulyRandom', 'UseCompoundDrawables', 'GradleDependency'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

// produces just the classes JAR
task jar(type: Copy, dependsOn:'bundleRelease') {
    from("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/bundles/release/")
    into("${project.buildDir}/libs/")
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', "appauth-${rootProject.versionName}.jar")
}

// produces a JAR containing sources
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:'generateReleaseSources') {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-Xlint:unchecked"
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply from: '../config/android-common.gradle'
apply from: '../config/keystore.gradle'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'net.openid.appauthdemo'
        project.archivesBaseName = 'appauth-demoapp'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        // Make sure this is consistent with the redirect URI used in res/raw/auth_config.json,
        // or specify additional redirect URIs in AndroidManifest.xml
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.lohika.android.test'
        ]
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debugAndRelease {
            storeFile file("${rootDir}/appauth.keystore")
            storePassword "appauth"
            keyAlias "appauth"
            keyPassword "appauth"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugAndRelease
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugAndRelease
        }
    }
}

project.ext.glideVersion = '4.7.1'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${project.glideVersion}"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.1'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10'

    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:${project.glideVersion}"
}

apply from: '../config/style.gradle'
```

Comment: I am struggling with the same thing... looking for a solution...

Comment: Have you managed to fix this?

Comment: android stuido gives option to move to androidX . have you tried out ?

Comment: Did this issue end up getting resolved for anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. In my case there is was problem with java language levels where the annotation processor runs on Java 9+, but android is compiled as Java 8 or lower. So adding org.gradle.java.home to build options worked:

> ./gradlew --info --scan --stacktrace --debug :app:clean :app:compileDebugSources -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home

Hope this helps

Answer (score -3):

This work fine for me:

```java
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.10.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.10.2'
```